# MYSQL DB Fast insert AND select

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and i want to make a table that is very fast with concurrent insertion and selection .
For example,I want to store 1 million rows in about less than 1 second and also read these rows whenever they are stored.

Any suggestions about the storage engine (MYISAM or InnoDB), how to fast insert all these rows and how to read them.

Thanks

Comment: And how do you insert the data?

Comment: Inserting a million rows in less than a second is very ambitious.  It requires the right processing power and network hardware.  You don't say how wide the rows are, but it is easy to imagine rows that are hundreds of bytes wide.  It sounds like you need a DBA and systems person on your team to help design what you want to do.  For most databases, the sweet spot is hundreds or thousands of transactions per second.

Comment: For reducing calls to the database you can use multiple rows in insert statement 

`INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage engine MyISAM is primarily for read-mostly workloads, because of locking at table level. If you really need concurrent insertion and selection, you'd rather choose the storage engine InnoDB, because it uses row locking. Be aware that InnoDB is a little bit slower because of the overhead.

In any case, make sure you're using batch inserts. Try to keep the number of indices on the table as low as possible to not have index creation overhead. Also you should configure your MySQL server for good performance. For example I would use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 in your MySQL server configuration, if you don't mind loosing one second of data when your server crashes. There are a few books on optimizing MySQL, look for "High Performance MySQL".

Besides software, also the hardware plays an important role. You're likely to be disk bound. Thus having a fast disk is essential (for example SSD or RAID).

Comment: "InnoDB is a little smaller" - what do you mean?